# laravel model binding for new record

Tags: php, laravel-5, model, eloquent

i use model binding for profile update like this :

```
{{ Form::model($profile, [
            'route' => [
                'client.update'
                ,$profile->user_id
            ]
            , 'method' => 'POST'
            , 'class' => 'form-horizontal'
        ])
    }}
```

but if the user has no profile information than the page get error because of :

```
$profile->user_id cos it does not exist in db
```

what can i do now ?

if the user has profile it could be update but not it could be save

Comment: Remove the `user_id` from the route. Pass it in a hidden field instead.

Comment: it is a solution which is a good idea but i can not do this because i want to find best solution . thanks for your advice @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Are you creating a profile to the authenticated user?

Comment: no . user has no profile at first . problem is exactly that

Comment: So what does the variable `$profile` hold?

Comment: it has some information about user like name - surname - picture - ip ...

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::model($profile, [
        'route' => [
            ($profile->exists)
              ? 'client.update', $profile->user_id
              : 'client.create'
        ]
        , 'method' => 'POST'
        , 'class' => 'form-horizontal'
    ])
}}
```

If the profile `exists` you know it's an existing record, so you can choose another route (and also another HTTP method. Typically you `post` for creation and `put` for update.)

Comment: i understood but i can not this put and post difference . if i make creating could i use put ? why ?

what is the difference ?

Comment: That's in case you want to make "RESTful" controllers. Consider http://stackoverflow.com/a/16761375/3208258 but also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/67553/198857